# What will happen if you attach the negative pole of welder to the rotor of the motor or the body , will that cause problem?

Tags: electrical, motors, welding, machining

I have built a machine that rotates a cylinder to weld it, I have to attache a negative pole to the cylinder which is connected directly to the rotor of motor, the motor is controled by a vfd , will that cause any issue to motor and vfd or not?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, **yes**, it will cause a problem. You need to isolate the VFD and motor away from the rotating cylinder or the welder will cause issues.

Comment: Your question may be better answered in welding forums where licensed, experienced welders can help. Describing in detail your custom machine gives them better info on do's and don'ts of welding.

Comment: @FDryer - Not sure why you are sending the individual to something exterior of SE? Also, how do you know I'm not an expert welder? Making broad assumptions. As with any electronic device, it should be detached electrically from anything you're welding on. The electrical surge during welding can and will cause damage.

Comment: I disagree as many welding operations take place with electronics remaining in place. I'm guessing you're not an expert on welding related to electrical or electronic circuits like vehicles when welding chassis sheet metal with all electronics still in place with precautions like disconnecting battery power. My redirection to more expert and experienced welding forums can easily answer this person's concern.

Comment: @FDryer - If you notice, I didn't say electronics couldn't be left in place, we do it all the time with auto welding. But you do disconnect the battery. I told the OP to isolate the electronics. I guess you aren't an expert at reading or welding or automotive work?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand the OP? He's attempting to rotate a cylinder while welding, requiring the VFD, adjustable speed to match welding speed. That's my interpretation of the post.

Comment: @FDryer - Your interpretation of the *question* would be wrong. Yes, the motor has to drive the rotating cylinder and the VFD has to connect to the motor. If the OP does this, there will most likely be an issue. If the motor is electrically isolated from the cylinder, the possibility of an issue from this will be eliminated. The OP just needs to drive the cylinder differently and all will be fine. Again, the question is about whether there will be a problem, not how to drive the cylinder.

Comment: I've watched several youtube videos of welders using a rotating table under electric power with speeds adjustable for welding speed using tig. Impressive show and tell. I don't see a problem here but stand on my interpretation of asking more experienced welders, excluding myself, hence the simple suggestion to find a welding forum for expertise and knowledge.

Comment: @FDryer - Fair enough. I would still ask you don't push people to other sites or suggest they go somewhere else. The whole idea of SE is to document the knowledge here. What you are doing is telling the OP is "*Don't come here with your questions. Go somewhere else.*"